# Alter behavior of "}" shortcut in Sublime Text 3 Vintage Mode

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3 Vintage Mode, the keyboard shortcut "}" performs the following command:

```
{
  "keys": ["}"],
  "command": "set_motion",
  "args": {
    "motion": "move",
    "motion_args": {
      "by": "stops",
      "empty_line": true,
      "extend": true,
      "forward": true,
      "separators": "",
      "word_begin": false
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find good documentation for set_motion and I'm not sure where to start to implement this from scratch.

**How do I change the behavior so that instead of moving to the next *empty line*, it moves to the next line with *only whitespace*?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't really help with the set_motion command, but doing it yourself via a plugin shouldn't be to bad. First off, here is a [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) to the ST3 API docs. You will be creating a `sublime_plugin.TextCommand`. Of particular interest  are `view#sel`, `view#line`, and `view#substr`.

`view#sel` will get you the position of the cursor(s).

`view#line` with a point passed in (initially retrieved from `view#sel`) will create give you a region of the entire line.

`view#substr` takes the region (result from `view#line`) and returns the string of the characters in that line. You can use a regular expression to see if that line contains only white space, and place the cursor appropriately. If the line does not meet the requirement, you can increase the second point in the region to move to the next line.

Hope that helps getting you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the head start! I will try this out and post if I get a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comment from the softwares author on the options availability for “by”: “stops”
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/restoring-st2-cursor-move-by-word-behaviour-in-st3-on-os-x/14035

```
If you need more control, then using the move command with “by”: “stops” should allow more configurability. When using stops, you need to tell the command which logical units to stop on. The options are:

"word_begin": false,
"word_end": false,
"punct_begin": false,
"punct_end": false,
"sub_word_begin": false,
"sub_word_end": false,
"line_begin": false,
"line_end": false,
"empty_line": false,
```